# What's the general word for cheese?

Tags: vocabulary

What's the general word for "cheese"? I've tryed to look it up in the dictionary but there are so many options!! What's the most general, the word that native speaker would use to say "I want a piece of cheese"?

Answer (score 4):

The general term in mainland China is 奶酪. 乳酪 is seen as well. 干酪 seems the standard term in Taiwan, where the phonetic translation 起司 is also seen. Hongkongese have a phonetic translation 芝士.

Comment: 起司 is used in Taiwan, not Hong Kong.

Comment: 芝士 is used commonly on the mainland as well, at least in my experience

Answer (score 3):

请给我一块奶酪。

Note that you shouldn't use the general classifier 个 for cheese.

Answer (score 2):

奶酪 nailao - cheese
我要一块奶酪。 - I want a piece of cheese.

Answer (score 2):

The general word for cheese in chinese would be "奶酪".